# osx error finding boost

Tags: boost, osx, ros-diamondback, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install diamondback on a brand new, fresh out of the box macbook pro, and I'm encountering an error that I've never seen before. I'm getting errors from

`diamondback/ros/tools/rosboost_cfg/src/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py`

about not being able to find boost.  The specific error is

`rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError: "Cannot find boost in any of [('/usr', True), ('/usr/local', True)]"`

Looking in the python script, it looks like this list should at the very least also include /opt/local/include, which is set in `$CPATH`.

Here's the relevant python bit:

```
 _search_paths = [(sysroot+'/usr', True),
                 (sysroot+'/usr/local', True),
                 (None if 'INCLUDE_DIRS' not in os.environ else os.environ['INCLUDE_DIRS'], True),
                 (None if 'CPATH' not in os.environ else os.environ['CPATH'], True),
                 (None if 'C_INCLUDE_PATH' not in os.environ else os.environ['C_INCLUDE_PATH'], True),
                 (None if 'CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH' not in os.environ else os.environ['CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH'], True),
                 (None if 'ROS_BOOST_ROOT' not in os.environ else os.environ['ROS_BOOST_ROOT'], False)]
```

When I do

`echo $CPATH`

I get

`/opt/local/include`

(set from .profile).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9375/osx-error-finding-boost/) by [Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/237/nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the problem.

It happens when doing `sudo rosinstall` instead of just `rosinstall`.

For future reference, `rosinstall` and `sudo` don't play well together on OSX currently.

---

Originally posted by [Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/237/nick/) with karma: 93 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2